# How do I move shortcut buttons into the GUI

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there anyway of moving common tasks like uncommenting code (I see I can only do it for a limited selection of things like refactoring etc) onto the main GUI as a button - much like visual studio's buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting and uncommenting code is cmd-/.

The general answer to this question is no.

Shortcut is handy.  Hit `cmd-shift-?` to bring down the help menu and put focus in the search field.  Type something like "comment" and it'll find matching menu items.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize with prebuilt actions by right/option-clicking on the toolbar and ->customize.

As for anything real custom, you have to learn the keyboard shortcuts for them.